# Xcode - Podfile not installing properly swiftvalidator

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am trying to install the SwiftValidator library ([Accessible here](https://github.com/jpotts18/SwiftValidator) but I am unable to get it to work.

Basically opened Terminal and cd to the directory of the xcode project. In there, I created a Podfile with the following content:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, "8.1"

use_frameworks!
pod 'SwiftValidator', '3.0.1'
```

and then after that I typed in terminal:

> pod install

This is the output I got in the console:

```
Updating local specs repositories

Updating spec repo `master`
  $ /usr/bin/git pull --ff-only
  From https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs
     435c890..1ee4098  master     -> origin/master
  Updating 435c890..1ee4098
  Fast-forward
   Specs/KMCache/0.1.1/KMCache.podspec.json | 20 ++++++++++++++++++++
   1 file changed, 20 insertions(+)
   create mode 100644 Specs/KMCache/0.1.1/KMCache.podspec.json

Analyzing dependencies

Inspecting targets to integrate
  Using `ARCHS` setting to build architectures of target `Pods`: (``)

Finding Podfile changes
  - SwiftValidator

Resolving dependencies of `Podfile`

Comparing resolved specification to the sandbox manifest
  - SwiftValidator

Downloading dependencies

-> Using SwiftValidator (3.0.1)
  - Running pre install hooks

Generating Pods project
  - Creating Pods project
  - Adding source files to Pods project
  - Adding frameworks to Pods project
  - Adding libraries to Pods project
  - Adding resources to Pods project
  - Linking headers
  - Installing targets
    - Installing target `SwiftValidator` iOS 8.1
      - Generating Info.plist file at `Pods/Target Support
      Files/SwiftValidator/Info.plist`
      - Generating module map file at `Pods/Target Support
      Files/SwiftValidator/SwiftValidator.modulemap`
      - Generating umbrella header at `Pods/Target Support
      Files/SwiftValidator/SwiftValidator-umbrella.h`
    - Installing target `Pods` iOS 8.1
      - Generating Info.plist file at `Pods/Target Support
      Files/Pods/Info.plist`
      - Generating module map file at `Pods/Target Support
      Files/Pods/Pods.modulemap`
      - Generating umbrella header at `Pods/Target Support
      Files/Pods/Pods-umbrella.h`
  - Running post install hooks
  - Writing Xcode project file to `Pods/Pods.xcodeproj`
    - Generating deterministic UUIDs
  - Writing Lockfile in `Podfile.lock`
  - Writing Manifest in `Pods/Manifest.lock`

Integrating client project

Integrating target `Pods` (`Mawq.xcodeproj` project)
  - Running post install hooks
    - cocoapods-stats from
    `/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-stats-0.6.2/lib/cocoapods_plugin.rb`

Sending stats
      - SwiftValidator, 3.0.1
  Pod installation complete! There is 1 dependency from the Podfile and 1 total
  pod installed.
```

Things seem great but when I open the project (not the .xcodeproj file but the .xcworkspace) and I type into the view controller class the following, it says it doesn't recognize the underlying module

```
import SwiftValidator
```

Any idea why this is happening when things seem to install correctly?

Update: Added image of the directory of the project...

[image]

Answer (score 1):

So this is unexpected. I had to actually build the project once and then when I typed the import statement it showed the SwiftValidator library.

This is unexpected because I installed other pods earlier and this was never required. Hope this helps the next person.

Answer (score 0):

maybe the framework isn't called SwiftValidator - check the Pods project's products and see what it generates in terms of frameworks

### JUST AN EXAMPLE showing where to look in Xcode.

[image]

Comment: had to rebuild the project. I guess something with dependencies needed updating. Unexpected, but works